# Update an item using a django model instance

Tags: python, django, database

Is it a good idea to update an item by saving a model instance with the same id if the fields that are different between the item and the instance are unknown?

Lets say there is an `Person` item in the database:

```
id: 4
name: Foo
surename: Bar
tel: 0000000000
```

Is it a good idea to update that item like:

```
p = Person(
    name='Foo'
    surename='Bar'
    tel='0000000111'
)

old_p = Person.objects.get(name='Foo', surname='Bar')
p.id = old_p.id

p.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it a good idea to update an item by saving a model instance with the same id?

**No**. If you `Person` model has other fields, you will need to copy all these fields in the new record `p`. Otherwise these might be updated to the default values the `Person` model has, or to the incorrect values you passed to the `p = Person(…)` call. This makes it hard to maintain code: each time you add a new field to a model, you need to update all code fragments where you update a single field.

If you want to update a single field, you can do this with an [**`.update(…)`** call [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update):

```
Person.objects.filter(name='Foo', surname='Bar').update(tel='0000000111')
```

or if you want to run triggers, and work with the `.save(…)` method of that model, you can retrieve the object, and update that specific field, so:

```
p = Person.objects.get(name='Foo', surname='Bar')
p.tel = '0000000111'
p.save()
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. In my case the fields to be updated are different each time and unknown. I have updated my question.

Comment: @Charalamm: but you can simply alter multiple fields and save the instance back. So all fields that you specified in the `Person(...)` constructor can be altered before saving the record back in the database.